# A asyncio task which open a tcp client to get msg. but It can not alway get the msg. sometimes it blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, task, python-asyncio

## 1.The server code

First write a simple tcp server. The code below is the server.

```py
import asyncio
import struct

counter = 0


async def on_connection(r: asyncio.StreamReader, w: asyncio.StreamWriter):
    msg = struct.pack("HB", 3, 0)
    w.write(msg)
    await w.drain()
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter, "client")


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connection, '0.0.0.0', 12345)
    await server.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The code will start tcp server listen on '0.0.0.0:12345'. I use to count how many client connected to the server. The server run at another matchine which ip address is 192.168.3.2

## 2.The client code

A simple client that used to test and count what happened when connect to server.

```py
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
counter = 0
c_counter = 0


async def connection_to():
    r, w = await asyncio.open_connection('192.168.3.2', 12345)
    global c_counter
    c_counter += 1
    print(c_counter, "connected")
    await r.readexactly(3)
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print(counter, "get_msg")


async def main():
    for i in range(7000):
        t = loop.create_task(connection_to())

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    print(e.with_traceback(None))
```

## 3. The question

Question why some task can not read the msg.
get_msg count != connect count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

backlog is too smail.
just make larger backlog can fix the problem.
tip:
make net.ipv4.somaxconn  larger too.